# Ableton will only play sound from library but not in workspace

Tags: ableton-live

Ableton only plays sounds from the library but not in the workspace.

I can only get sounds to play from the library in Ableton, but when I move something into the workspace it remains mute.

I have the Novation midi keyboard hooked up to it, so it does most things automatically from the keyboard. I tried the keyboard with Arturia and it worked. So I know that it is something in the Ableton area. I have tried the ASIO audio format along with Direct X. I have them both synced to the speaker on my graphics card as my others stopped working, strangely.

Does anyone have any idea what the problem could be?

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/yg58nx16erl953m/Screenshot%20%285%29.png?dl=0



https://www.dropbox.com/s/w6hzli5td6wmhzz/Screenshot%20%284%29.png?dl=0

Comment: Even the metronome works in the sound that it makes. But, still nothing from the work space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I understand where the confusion is. An .adv file is an instrument preset file. To use it in the Session view, after dragging it onto a MIDI track, you need to create a clip with notes that play the instrument, like in this screenshot:

[image: Playing an instrument]

I agree that it can be confusing that items in the Sounds section are previewed and presented as a small waveform when you click them in the Browser, but then need to be played with notes when you actually use them in the Session view.

Comment: For some reason my comment was deleted. How do you create a clip? The insert clip icon in the create tab is greyed out. So I could not figure out how to do that.

Comment: Okay, I figured it out. Just double click on an empty slot below the sound to create a clip and it is working now! Thanks alot!

Answer (score 0):

I think what it is is that a driver is required for the MIDI. Which means that it has to be on ASIO in the audio settings with the driver selected. On Arturia it just picks the MIDI up so I figured it would be the same. However, with Garritan I was required to install the driver. But, for the Novation midi keyboard designed for Ableton, the MIDI has to be connected to the computer through an audio interface, because for some reason it will not read the driver through the USB connection as Garritan does.

Comment: When you say 'move the sound to the workspace', do you mean that you moved the .adv file to another folder on your disk? Or do you mean you dragged the sound to the session view?

Comment: Well the sound to the session view is I believe what it would categorize as what you are inferring to. Selecting a .adv file or some other type of sound file in the library and activating it for use in the session to however you so please.